# create tables from existing tables without copying data in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would like to create tables from existing tables without copying the data to the new tables in snowflake. Is this possible?

For example:

I have tables say "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb1" and "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb2".

I would like to create tables "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb3" and "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb4" from "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb1" and "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb2" without copying their data to "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb3" and "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb4".

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer for above question is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb3" LIKE "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb1"

CREATE TABLE "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb4" LIKE "DB"."SCHEMA"."tb2"
```

Answer (score 1):

As rightly mentioned, "LIKE" operator when used with "create table" would create a table from parent without copying the data.

Here is the documentation for this command and example : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html